# Is there a faster way on reading, writing and saving excel files?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multiprocessing, openpyxl

I am new to Python. Currently I need to count the number of duplicates, delete the duplicate ones and update the duplicates occasions into a new column. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


filepath = '/Users/jordanliu/Desktop/test/testA.xlsx'
data = load_workbook(filepath)


sku = data.active

duplicate_column = []
for x in range(sku.max_row):

    duplicate_count = 0

    for i in range(x):
        if sku.cell(row =i + 2, column = 1).value == sku.cell(row = x + 2, column = 1).value:
            duplicate_count = duplicate_column[i] + 1
            sku.cell(row =i+2, column = 1).value = 0

    duplicate_column.append(duplicate_count)


for x in range(len(duplicate_column)):
    sku.cell(row=x + 2, column=3).value = duplicate_column[x]

for y in range(sku.max_row):
    y = y + 1
    if sku.cell(row = y, column = 1).value == 0:
        sku.delete_rows(y,1)


data.save(filepath)
```

I've tried using both pandas but because the execution time takes extraordinary long, I've decided to change to openpyxl but it doesn't seem to help much. Many from other post have suggest to use CSV but because its the writing process that takes the majority of the time I thought that it wouldn't help much. 
Can someone please provide me some help here?

Comment: If this works, and you're just trying to make it more efficient, I suggest instead posting it over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: will definitely do so thank you

Comment: You should really follow the examples in the documentation as they make the code a lot easier to read. The short answer is that this probably can be done faster but you need to provide more information about exactly where the duplicates are, how big the file is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for x in range(sku.max_row):

    duplicate_count = 0

    for i in range(x):
        if sku.cell(row =i + 2, column = 1).value == sku.cell(row = x + 2, column = 1).value:
            duplicate_count = duplicate_column[i] + 1
            sku.cell(row =i+2, column = 1).value = 0
```

For this portion, you are rechecking the same values over and over. Assuming these should be unique totally, which is how I think your code is written, then you should instead implement a cache of a hashed type (dict or set) to do these subsequent lookups instead of doing the lookup via `sku.cell` every time.

So it would be something like:

```py
xl_cache = {}
duplicate_count = {}
delete_set = set()
for x in range(sku.max_row):
    x_val = sku.cell(row = x, column = 1).value
    if x_val in xl_cache:   # then this is not first time
        xl_cache[x_val][1] += 1   # increase duplicate count
        delete_set.add(x)
    else:
        xl_cache[x_val] = x   # key is value for duplicate cache, value is row number
        duplicate_count[x] = 0   # key is row number, value is duplicate count
```

So now you have a dictionary of originals with duplicate counts, you need to go back and delete your rows that you don't want plus change the duplicate counts in the sheet. So go backwards through the range and delete the row or update the duplicate count. You can do this by going to your max first and reducing by 1, check for delete first, otherwise change the duplicate.

```py
y = sku.max_row
for i in range(y, 0, -1):
    if i in delete_set:
        sku.delete_rows(i,1)
    else:
        sku.cell(row=i, column=3) = duplicate_count[i]
```

In theory, this would only traverse your range twice in total, and lookups from the cache would be O(1) on average. You need to traverse this in reverse to maintain row order as you delete rows.

Since I don't actually have your sample data I can't test this code completely so there could be minor issues but I tried to use the structures that you have in your code to make it easily usable for you.

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for your help. The code really had brought me a new perspective of thinking and drag me from the desperation that I was in. However, I'd still have some questions for you.

Comment: First, considering first column regarding reading and writing the duplicate occurence, because there is a third column in excel along with column 1 & 2, I'm worried that using dictionary might not stored its value. I'm really sorry for not pointing this out earlier

Comment: Second, as to the last picture, I was not quite understand the part where " duplicate_count[x]" still has the x despite its in the for loop of indice i. do u mean by putting that i for loop inside the previous x for loop?

Comment: So you aren’t storing any value in the dictionary except for the row number. As far as comparison, if you are comparing multiple columns then I would cache per column unless you’re comparing any value in 1 or 2 to any value in 1 or 2. In which case you would cache together.

Comment: The basic idea is to implement a cache as a hash table rather than do continuous excel lookups. You keep your excel worksheet in tact and figure out a list of all the changes you need to make, then you go through and make them but ensuring any change doesn’t mess up any future change (like if you store row number but delete row 3, now every future row number would have to be adjusted, instead go backwards so it doesn’t matter what you delete).

Comment: If this has improved your performance, please click the check mark next to the answer @JordanLiu